# Wildfly instance is always running on port 8080 even when no server is running

Tags: jakarta-ee

So since I installed a Wildfly instance with Intellij yesterday it seems that even if I don't run a Jboss server there will always be an instance of Wildfly running on the port 8080, even if I run a TomCat server instead it will launch me on a Wildfly page.

I'm new to JEE and I have a lot of trouble atm to make multiple JSP files work together and atm I feel like my server config isn't done properly.

I checked the 8080 port in cmd like I saw some people advising to do here but when I run netstat it doesn't show anything on 8080, so I can't even shut it down by force.

Is there a way to completely shutdown this Wildfly server to free up my 8080 port ?

Is it normal for it to be accessible when no IDE is running ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Try cleaning the browser cache (that's why tomcat would show you wildfly page). Skype on Windows uses 8080 so try stopping it.

Comment: Ok thanks ! It worked , feels kinda stupid to try every option instead of the simple one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try cleaning the browser cache (that's why tomcat would show you wildfly page).
- Skype on Windows uses 8080 so try stopping it.